# Exporting angularjs module as es6 module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, babeljs, es6-module-loader

You are supposed to wrap angularjs modules in an IIFE according to the styleguide, which we use

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#iife

my-dir.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('my.dir', [])
        .controller('MyDirController', MyDirController),
        .directive('my-dir', MyDirDirective);

    function MyDirController() {

    }

    function MyDirDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: MyDirController
        }
    }
})();
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', ['my.dir'])
})();
```

But as we are now using webpack to bundle es6 modules. How are we supposed to use this IIFE and `export`? We can't do `export default angular.module('my-dir', [])` as export must be a top-level command. Also, we should just be returning a string of the name of the module? So that it can be included as a require in the `app` module. What is best practice?

This works, but you have to retype the module name, and seems a bit messy having the export outside the IIFE (Which I assume has to be the case)

```
(function() {
    angular.module('my.dir', [])
        .controller('MyDirController', MyDirController)
        .directive('my-dir', MyDirDirective);

    function MyDirDirective(appPath) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            bindToController: {},
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            template: '<div ng-bind="$ctrl.msg"></div>',
            controller: MyDirController
        };
    }

    function MyDirController() {
        var self = this;
        self.msg = "Hello World";
    }
})();
export default 'my.dir'
```

Comment: I would guess that comments about using IIFE in the Angular style guide do not apply when using tools like babel or webpack. These tools solve those concerns for you as well. With webpack/babel you can take other approaches to writing your code: write the above as a commonjs module (w/no IIFE), convert the above to a Typescript or ES6 class, etc. It might be a bit of redundant work to convert your code base, but the long term benefits are well worth it :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After moving to modules, the new structure has become

app.js

```
import myDir from './my-dir.js'

angular.module('app', [myDir.name]);
```

my-dir.js

```
// import template from './my-dir.html'; // Can use this with template property

export default angular.module('my.dir', [])
    .controller('MyDirController', MyDirController)
    .directive('my-dir', MyDirDirective);

function MyDirDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {},
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: '<div ng-bind="$ctrl.msg"></div>',
        controller: MyDirController
    };
}

function MyDirController() {
    const self = this;  // Not needed if using arrow functions
    self.msg = "Hello World";
}
```

The IIFE is no longer needed as now everything is by default a module if always using any kind of javascript module system

Comment: did you use webpack to compile this?